# Radiant CMS: Meta-tag errors

Tags: ruby, radiant

While attempting to migrate an old website from an end of life server which utilizes a cms built in ruby called Radiant; we have also decided to upgrade to the most current version of the CMS (which appears to no longer be maintained).

Built into Radiant is a pseudo-code processor which converts an unique mark-up to html (https://github.com/radiant/radiant/wiki/Tags-that-insert-content) and functioned correctly in the older version of the software. With the newer version the processor appears to work with the exception of two (rather important) tags/fields the meta keywords and meta description

The code in question is:

```
<r:meta:description tag="true"/>
<r:meta:keywords tag="true" />
```

which is outputting:

```
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
```

where as in previous versions it had no functional issues.

If there is a configuration we have missed, or a file we can modify to easily correct this any insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a capilization issue in the database (namely the page_field table and the name column; switching values from "Description" and "Keywords" to "descriptions" and "keywords" corrected the errors